# What is proper procedure for linking to a stylesheet when there's ajax involved

Tags: html, css, ajax

I'm using ajax to replace the content of a div in my page.

The div has initial default content which is part of the same html file, of which the style would be controlled by css.

But then when i replace the contents with another file, how does the styling work? Would css apply the same properties that were used for the div before it got switched out? Also what happens if i put a link for another stylesheet directly on the page which has the content for the new div?

I guess im just not sure how to prevent my styling of the initial div to interfere with my styling of the new div, and wondering what proper protocol is.

Comment: Not yet, I figured that even if i observed a desired result, i wouldnt know if my way was proper protocol or if i was missing any unforeseen problems. Better safe than sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS styles are applied to every matching selector on the page, whether the content is dynamically loaded or not. If you don't want the old styles to interfere with the new content, don't use the same IDs / classes (or selectors).